# Naive Bayes Classification Example

Tags: probability, bayesian, data-mining, naive-bayes

Given the following data:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{Instance} & \text{A} & \text{B} &\text{C} &\text{Class} \\ \hline
\text{1} & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{2}& 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{3} & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{4} & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{5} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{6} & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{7} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Predit the class label for instance $(A=1, B=2, C=2)$ using naive Bayes classifcation.

Let $C_{1}$ be class $1$ and $C_{2}$ be class $2$.
I have so far that the class prior probabilties are:

$$P(C_{1})=\dfrac{4}{7}$$ $$P(C_{2})=\dfrac{3}{7}$$

Using Bayes Theorem: $$P(C{i}|X)=\dfrac{P(X|C{i})P(C_{i})}{P(X)}$$

I know that $P(X|C_{i})=\prod^{n}_{k=1}P(X_{k}|C_{i})$ but not sure how to calculate this.

Where do I go from here to go about answering the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $C_1$, by the assumption of Naive Bayesian Classifier, we have
$$
P(A = 1, B = 2, C=2 \mid C_1) = P(A = 1 \mid C_1) \cdot P(B = 2 \mid C_1) \cdot P(C = 2 \mid C_1)
$$
Take $P(A = 1 \mid C_1)$ as an example. There are $4$ training records of $C_1$, among which there are $2$ records with $A = 1$. Therefore, $P(A = 1 \mid C_1) = \frac{2}{4}$. Similarly, you can calculate $P(B = 2 \mid C_1)$ and $P(C = 2 \mid C_1)$.

It is similar to calculate $P(A = 1, B = 2, C = 2 \mid C_2)$.

Comment: Then does the highest probability predict the class?

Comment: @SophieFiler Exactly. Note that you do not need to consider the term $P(X)$ in your formula since it is contained in both probabilities.

Comment: @PSPACEhard   P(A=1,B=2,C=2∣C1)=P(A=1∣C1)⋅P(B=2∣C1)⋅P(C=2∣C1)  , p(x) is not needed as its commn but what about p(y) shpuld we multiply it as last  after finding P(A=1,B=2,C=2∣C1) ?